# How to handle UITextField position while typing in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Its very common problem in iOS mobile development and that is while you are done with your UI and It contains too many UITextFields, If you try to input value in UITextFields those are added center bottom of the screen; these fields hides behind the keyboard. How can we get rid of this general problem?

Comment: Guys, Please mentioned why you down voting it, so that I can improve and work on that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used a `nuget` package to get rid of this problem. I have overrides two methods and initialized code inside these methods.

Download [KeyboardHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Keyboard.Handler/) and use as following:

```
using KeyboardHandler;


public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
  base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
  this.yourScrollView.SubscribeKeyboardManaqger();
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
  base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
  this.yourScrollView.UnsubscribeKeyboardManaqger();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the AddObserver method in NSNotificationCenter for when keyboard is visible and hidden.

sample code(FYI: Got the code below from another post sometime last year, I can't remember link to the post but it works fine.)

Call the AddObserver in your viewdidload method

// Keyboard popup            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.DidShowNotification, KeyBoardUpNotification);

// Keyboard Down            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification, KeyBoardDownNotification);

you can add the methods below in your base controller base if you have one

```
 public void KeyBoardUpNotification(NSNotification notification) {
            CGRect keyboardSize = UIKeyboard.BoundsFromNotification(notification);

            // Find what opened the keyboard
            foreach (UIView view in this.View.Subviews) {
                if (view.IsFirstResponder)
                    activeview = view;
            }

            bottom = (activeview.Frame.Y + activeview.Frame.Height + offset);
            scrollamount = (keyboardSize.Height - (View.Frame.Size.Height - bottom));

            if (scrollamount > 0) {
                moveViewUp = true;
                MoveView(moveViewUp);
            } else {
                moveViewUp = false;
            }

        }

     public void KeyBoardDownNotification(NSNotification notification) {
                if (moveViewUp) {
                    MoveView(false);
                }
            }

private void MoveView(bool move) {
            UIView.BeginAnimations(string.Empty, IntPtr.Zero);
            UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.3);
            CGRect frame = View.Frame;

            if (move) {
                frame.Y -= scrollamount;
            } else {
                frame.Y += scrollamount;
                scrollamount = 0;
            }

            View.Frame = frame;
            UIView.CommitAnimations();
        }
```

Comment: Thank @megaKertz. Why should I use it? While I can do it in 2 lines of code!
FYI this is not idle approach and it has lot of leaks and result also unexpected while typing!

Comment: @RIYAZ Never said you should use it, you could if you think it's solves the issue you're having. so what's the 2 lines of code you used

Comment: Sorry bro I didn't mean that. I used it and found lot of issue in this code, ScrollView was behaving weird so I removed this.